# How to delete large quantity of records from Oracle Table that has no primary key

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle

The situation: I'm loading an entire SQL table into my program. For convenience I'm using pandas to maintain the row data. I am then creating a dataframe of rows I would like to have removed from the SQL table. Unfortunately (**and I can't change this**) the table does not have any primary keys other than the built-in Oracle ROWID (which isn't a real table column its a pseudocolumn), but I can make ROWID part of my dataframe if I need to.

The table has hundreds of thousands of rows, and I'll probably be deleting a few thousand records with each run of the program.

Question:
**Using Cx_Oracle what is the best method of deleting multiple rows/records that don't have a primary key?** I don't think creating a loop to submit thousands of delete statements is very efficient or pythonic. Although I am concerned about building a singular SQL delete statement keyed off of ROWID and that contains a clause with thousands of items:

```
Where ROWID IN ('eg1','eg2',........, 'eg2345')
```

Is this concern valid? Any Suggestions?

Comment: I don't know CX-Oracle specifically, but I've generated very substantial "IN" clauses like this in the past in TSQL and never had a problem.  I say try it . . . if there is a limit it is probably large can so you could change your code to do 1024 at a time (or whatever limit was imposed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using ROWID

Since you can use `ROWID`, that would be the ideal way to do it. And depending on the Oracle version, the query length limit may be large enough for a query with that many elements in the `IN` clause. The issue is the *number of elements* in the `IN` expression list - [limited to 1000](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27246746/Maximum-string-length-for-IN-statement-in-ORACLE-11-g-where-clause.html).

So you'll either have to break up the list of RowIDs into sets of 1000 at a time or delete just a single row at a time; with or without `executemany()`.

```
>>> len(delrows)  # rowids to delete
5000
>>> q = 'DELETE FROM sometable WHERE ROWID IN (' + ', '.join(f"'{row}'" for row in delrows) + ')'
>>> len(q)  # length of the query
55037
>>> # let's try with just the first 1000 id's and no extra spaces
... q = 'DELETE FROM sometable WHERE ROWID IN (' + ','.join(f"'{row}'" for row in delrows[:1000]) + ')'
>>> len(q)
10038
```

You're probably within query-length limits, and can even save some chars with a minimal `','` item separator.

#### Without ROWID

Without the Primary Key or ROWID, the only way to identify each row is to specify all the columns in the WHERE clause and to do many rows at a time, they'll need to be OR'd together:

```
DELETE FROM sometable
WHERE  ( col1 = 'val1'
         AND col2 = 'val2'
         AND col3 = 'val3' )  -- row 1
    OR ( col1 = 'other2'
         AND col2 = 'value2'
         AND col3 = 'val3' )  -- row 2
    OR ( ... )                -- etc
```

As you can see it's not the nicest query to construct but allows you to do it without ROWIDs.

---

And in both cases, you probably don't need to be using parameterised queries since the `IN` list in 1 or `OR` grouping in 2 is variable. (Yes, you could create it parameterised after constructing the whole extended SQL with thousands of parameters. Not sure what the limit is on that.) The `executemany()` way is definitely easier to write & do but for speed, the single large queries (either of the above two) will probably outperform executemany with thousands of items.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the situation!

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor.executemany() to delete multiple rows at once. Something like the following should work:

```
dataToDelete = [['eg1'], ['eg2'], ...., ['eg2345']]
cursor.executemany("delete from sometable where rowid = :1", dataToDelete)
```